# Double integrals over general regions and continuity

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, continuity

We know that:

Given a general bounded region D that can be enclosed in a rectangular region R and a function $f:D \to \Re$, we can define a function F such that it takes the values of f if (x, y) is in D or 0 if (x, y) isn't in D. From here we just define the integral of f over D:

$\int\int_Df(x,y)dA=\int\int_RF(x,y)dxdy$

I have a question regarding continuity of the function F:

F could have discontinuities at D's boundary, but we know the integral written above still works if f is continuous in D and D's boundary is the union of a finite number of smooth curves .

My question is why? I thought it might be because the volume under a curve is zero, much like the area under a point is zero. But I'm not sure whether that's the idea behind it or not.

I was also wondering if there is an actual proof for this (the fact that it still works in spite of F not being continuous at D's boundary) or any formal explanation.

Comment: You might need to turn to measure theory for a formal explanation. If the boundary of $D$, denoted $\partial D$, is a finite number of smooth curves, then it has measure zero inside of $R$.  The integral doesn't change if you add/subtract regions of measure zero (this is capturing exactly your intuition that "the volume under a curve is zero"), hence 
$$ \iint_R (\dots) \,dA = \iint_{R\setminus\partial D} (\dots) \,dA $$

Comment: @AlkaKadri I see, thank you very much! Also, is there any reason why the curves must be smooth? How does a continuous non-zero derivative influence the definition of the integral? Or do we want this hypothesis to garantee our curve is continuous (given that it is differentiable if it's smooth)? (I don't think this second idea is right tho, as why would we ask the curve to be smooth and not just continuous?)

Comment: There are some pathological examples of curves, such as the Peano curve (or other "space filling" curves), that can have non-zero measure if you don't add the smoothness condition! You can relax "smooth", however, to something like piecewise smooth without much trouble (e.g., the boundary of a square is piecewise smooth).